# Convert from object to byte[] while adding to a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm making an ASP MVC web app and I'm trying to load images from an SQLite database, adding them to a list and showing them in my view.

In my model, I have an image like this:

```
public Byte Image { get; set; }
```

I'm trying to read it and add it like this:

```
public List<ImageModel> Images { get; set; }

using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        list.Add(new ImageModel
                        {

                            Image = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(rdr["image"]) // error
                        });
                    }
                    rdr.Close();
                    Images = list;
                }
```

But it gives me a "cannot convert from object to byte[]". Any hints as to how I can approach this?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static byte[] Serialize(object obj)
{
    var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    binaryFormatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

And then

```
Image = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(Serialize(rdr["image"]))
```

And for deserializing:

```
public static object Deserialize(byte[] data)
{
    var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(data));
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. That sure got me a lot closer, but I get a "Cannot implicitly convert type string to byte[]" in the line where I serialize it and add it in the list. Changing the type in the model from Byte to String also doesn't help, because then it just outputs a huge string in the View.